# BATCH evading admin rights

Tags: batch-file

I have written a code that almost works.
the only part that doesn't work is when it needs to copy from the Z: drive to the C:\Program Files\software

That step requires to run the batch as an admin, however i would like to run it withouth admin rights.

I want to make it executable for every user in the domain, withouth having to give them admin rights.

Is this possible to do (also withouth having to copy the map for every single computer)

TL;DR
To copy a file to the C: drive the user would need to be an admin or run it as admin. However i don't want to make everyone admin so they can execute it.
Is there a way to evade this? Or some code i can put it to make non-admin users be able to copy to that folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possibly the `runas` command?

Comment: Will that enable to run it withouth admin rights.
And i don't need to enter the admin name and password then?

Comment: @Monacraft Will that enable to run it withouth admin rights. And i don't need to enter the admin name and password then?

Comment: You will need to enter the password each time. And technically you will be running it in admin mode.

Comment: @Monacraft So there is no possibility to run it as non-admin?
that will determine if i can automatically execute the file or not for everyone

Comment: The `Program Files` tree requires admin + elevation (if UAC is enabled) to write.  Choose a different destination -- perhaps `%APPDATA%` or `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`.

Comment: @rojo Would it be more handy if i put a link to the code?

Comment: Wouldn't change my answer, no.  `Program Files` is a restricted location regardless of your code.

Comment: @rojo But the problem is that i'm not sure if i can change the location.
It might be that it needs to be in `Program Files`

Comment: Then make sure the context under which the batch script runs has admin rights.  If you don't want to ensure your users have admin rights, then use a system account.  Ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) how to do this.

Comment: @rojo I'm sorry, but i'm not yet that experienced with IT.
Alot of things are new for me, i don't understand the system account for example (what is it, where to find it, and what does it do?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply change the security options for the target folder? Just give any user a write permission for it.

It makes no sense - if a user can't write to a location it's because of the security policy. If there was a way to allow a user to write to a location even if he isn't allowed to you would simply evade the windows security policy - which is not possible or at least not intended.

TL;DR: Ither grant the users the permission to write to the desired location by changing the security settings for the target dir OR by elevating the users' rights.